# indentation not as expected in VIM

Tags: vim

I have set ts=4 in vimrc file. So, one tab moves the cursor worth 4 spaces.

I use the `=i{` command to indent the block of code but when I do that, the indentation comes to the effect of indenting the code inside the {} by 8 space characters or 2 tabs, if I do it manually.

How do I make VIM on indent my code by 4 spaces or 4 tab space size when I am using the `=i{` command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `shiftwidth` as well:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

And if you want a tab character instead of 4 spaces, do this also:

```
set noexpandtab
```

Comment: yep, thanks. was about to answer my own question, saw your answer. For some reason, it's not letting me accept the answer until 10 mins. Admins, if I forget to come back and tick it , please accept this answer on my behalf.